# MFC CRecordSet snapshot support (is missing?) after migration from VC6 to VS2019

Tags: mfc, cdatabase, crecordset

We made a migration our old (>20 years) project from VC6 to VS2019 (v142).
Everything is working well, except one unpleasant thing: our CRecordSet objects act now in dynaset mode. As result: super slow working on poor connection. Because dynaset forces dataset to fetch any changes from server o ANY gui updates. When you scroll/resize/sort/.. you will have several seconds delay with ui block by network communications.

Previously, the same code worked in snapshop mode, it means, it was load only once and after change where NOT synchronized with remote server on any user action, result: very fast and responsible gui experience.

I found the information about breaking changes in VS2012 for this: [CRecordset::snapshot doesn't work in VS2012 anymore - what's the alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12714310/crecordsetsnapshot-doesnt-work-in-vs2012-anymore-whats-the-alternative)

But I got this error message when obtaining the data: "no columns were bound prior to calling sqlfetchscroll/sqlextendedfetch"

So my question is: is it possible to use real static CRecordSet as it was old good times? Without alltime synchronization.

Thanks.